# How to execute NOT in more than once

Tags: sql, presto

I had to get user_id in the following format,where I have to use NOT IN more than once in presto. It is giving the following error-

Query failed (#20210709_131827_01150_v2wkt): line 15:1: mismatched input 'select'. Expecting: '('

Can anyone help me in correcting the following query changing the input.

```
select user_id from gold.order_master_bi

where  portfolio  = 'Women Sarees'
and  order_date>=current_date-interval '30' day

and  user_id NOT IN

(select user_id,cast(year||'-'||month||'-'||day as date)
from silver.mixpanel_android__add_to_cart_clicked

where cast(year||'-'||month||'-'||day as date)=DATE('2021-07-09')

AND user_id NOT IN

select user_id
FROM gold.order_master_bi
where order_date=DATE('2021-07-09'))
```

Comment: It says right there in your error message: line 15:1: mismatched input 'select'. Expecting: '('

Comment: You might want to provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.  There might be alternative ways to write the query.

Comment: Basically I am trying to get information of those users who have added a product to the cart (add to cart table) and have not placed the order (order_master)

Answer (score 0):

It should be commas between statements inside `NOT IN`

```
select user_id from gold.order_master_bi

where  portfolio  = 'Women Sarees'
and  order_date>=current_date-interval '30' day

and  user_id NOT IN

(select user_id,cast(year||'-'||month||'-'||day as date)
from silver.mixpanel_android__add_to_cart_clicked

where cast(year||'-'||month||'-'||day as date)=DATE('2021-07-09')

,select user_id
FROM gold.order_master_bi
where order_date=DATE('2021-07-09'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got what are you doing right, there are these issues:

1. NOT IN subquery should not contain extra columns
2. Missing )

Format your code, it will help to understand and debug

```
    select user_id 
      from gold.order_master_bi
     where portfolio  = 'Women Sarees'
       and order_date>=current_date-interval '30' day
       and user_id NOT IN (select user_id 
                             from silver.mixpanel_android__add_to_cart_clicked
                            where cast(year||'-'||month||'-'||day as date)=DATE('2021-07-09') 
                              and user_id NOT IN (select user_id
                                                    from gold.order_master_bi
                                                   where order_date=DATE('2021-07-09')
                                                 )
                          )
```